# Алгоритм отправки сообщения выбранным пользователям

Tags: php, mysqli

Может вопрос прозвучит довольно глупым, но прошу сильно не ругать. Вообщем есть некая система и нужно организовать отправку сообщения пользователям внутри этой системы. Насчет отправки сообщения всем пользователям всё понятно. Например в базе есть стандартные поля к примеру `id, send_date, message_body, read_status user_id` (думаю тут все понятно) и при отображении сообщения из базы выбираются все записи ( в нашем случае сообщения) где  `read_status=0`. 
А вот как быть с отправкой сообщения только выбранным пользователям чтобы сообщения  которые адресованы только ему отображались только у него. Как спроектировать таблицу в БД ?
Пользователи кому нужно отправить сообщение выбираются с помощью bootstrap select multiple
Таблица пользователей usertable и таблица сообщений messagetable и связываются они через ID пользователя.

Comment: Как хочешь проектируй. Передавай из своего селекта id пользователей в обработчик например и в условии `where` выбирай по айдишникам

Comment: Пробовал так, но считай если каждое сообщение идет 10000 пользователям и таких сообщений в день например 100000 то вскоре уже БД начнет зависать думаю...

Comment: после отправки, статус меняется на 1 ?

Comment: А как бы других путей нет, нужен список кому отправлять (да еще со статусами чтения), значит его надо хранить. и да, в отдельной таблице. Я бы ее отделил от той таблицы, в которой сам текст сообщения, что бы не дублировать его (это нарушает НФ и занимает много места). И того выйдет что то типа id_сообщения, id_пользователя, дата_прочтения. при наличии индексов запросы информации по одному пользователю быстро будут работать. но конечно какая нибудь общая аналитика может быть тяжела для БД